# Boost Bind and async_wait

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, bind, handler

I am using boost library for some time based events .Where I want to call a static member function as handler on timer expiry , So can I  pass static member function as handler for `async_wait` in boost ?

I am getting error like below

```
SdkTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
SdkTest.cpp:89:55: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
     timerC.async_wait(boost::bind(&Sample::onTimerC), this);
```

Comment: For static member function which doesn't take any parameters, the following `timerC.async_wait(boost::bind(&Sample::onTimerC));` is sufficient. You should provide MCVE example, handler for `async_wait` takes error as parameter in its callback, so it is missing here..

Comment: Actually, `timerC.async_wait(&Sample::onTimerC);` is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !!! :) it worked